# Group JSON data by two properties in C#

Tags: c#, json, arraylist, group-by, json.net

I am trying to display and group json data and group the components and results of the entire array by one unique ID and then by date (for all the components and results in the array).

I already took the data from the json file, now i am stuck with grouping the data..

Any help is appreciated, Thanks!

Patients.cs:

```
namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Patient
    {

        public int ID{ get; set; }
        public string component { get; set; }
        public string result { get; set; }
        public string date { get; set; }
    }

    class Patients
    {
        public List<Patient> patients;
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

[image: TABLE]

Comment: Likely LINQ `GroupBy` will be involved. Show some code.

Comment: @Rotem Updated!

Comment: If you're already able to deserialize the data from JSON And populate the patients list then you can omit the entire JSON and first code block from your question, it will make it easier to answer. Also there are plenty of questions on SO dealing with `GroupBy`, what exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: @Rotem I am having trouble with the logic behind this: I need each component and result (from all separate objects) shown for one ID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to group your patient data with `ID` and `Date` so you can do this by using linq.

```
...
JsonResponse = objReader.ReadLine();
Patients patients = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Patients>(JsonResponse);

var result = (from p in patients.patients
              group p by new { p.ID, p.date } into grp
              select new
              {
                  Key = grp.Key,
                  Items = grp.ToList()
              }).ToList();

foreach (var item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Key.ID);
    Console.WriteLine(item.Key.date);
    Console.WriteLine();

    item.Items.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine($"ID: {x.ID}, date: {x.date}, result: {x.result}, component: {x.component}"));
    Console.WriteLine();
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

**Output:**

```
1030
10/19/2018

ID: 1030, date: 10/19/2018, result: 1, component: A
ID: 1030, date: 10/19/2018, result: 2, component: B
ID: 1030, date: 10/19/2018, result: 3, component: C
ID: 1030, date: 10/19/2018, result: 4, component: D
ID: 1030, date: 10/19/2018, result: 5, component: E

1031
12/12/2019

ID: 1031, date: 12/12/2019, result: 6, component: A
ID: 1031, date: 12/12/2019, result: 7, component: B
ID: 1031, date: 12/12/2019, result: 8, component: C
ID: 1031, date: 12/12/2019, result: 9, component: D
ID: 1031, date: 12/12/2019, result: 10, component: E
```

**Edit:**

For your custom output that you shown in your screenshot.

```
...
var result = (from p in patients.patients
              group p by new { p.ID, p.date } into grp
              select new
              {
                  Key = grp.Key,
                  Items = grp.ToList()
              }).ToList();

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("ID");
dt.Columns.Add("DATUM");

foreach (var item in result.Select(x => x.Items).FirstOrDefault())
{
    dt.Columns.Add(item.component);
}

foreach (var item in result)
{
    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["ID"] = item.Key.ID;
    dr["DATUM"] = item.Key.date;

    foreach (var innerItem in item.Items)
    {
        dr[innerItem.component] = innerItem.result;
    }

    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}

foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"ID: {row["ID"]}, DATUM: {row["DATUM"]}, A: {row["A"]}, B: {row["B"]}, C: {row["C"]}, D: {row["D"]}, E: {row["E"]}");
}
```

**Output:**

```
ID: 1030, DATUM: 10/19/2018, A: 1, B: 2, C: 3, D: 4, E: 5
ID: 1030980, DATUM: 12/12/2019, A: 6, B: 7, C: 8, D: 9, E: 10
```

Comment: Wow, Great! This is almost what i needed, see my updated code to see what the result should look like, I need each component and result shown for one ID (the logic behind this is what confuses me :( ).

Comment: Actually, this works great! I just removed the ID and Date keys from Console.Writeline(); and i got what I wanted, sorry for complicating, and thank you ! :)

Comment: Can I ask one more question? Can I show this data in two rows in console app (just like the update in my post)?

Comment: @DevShieldMaiden, answer updated. kindly view **Edit** section in answer with output :)

Comment: Thank you a lo! This has been bugging me for a few days now :)

Comment: @DevShieldMaiden, please rollback your question to version 5 so it can maintain integrity of question and answer :) i think version 5 doesn't contains any personal data it contain only screenshot you provided :)

Comment: @DevShieldMaiden, can i rollback your question to version 5 if you don't know how to do it? if your question integrity loses then it can be downvoted in future and then after threshold you will not be able to post new question

Comment: I do not know how to do that, so yes you can.

Comment: @DevShieldMaiden, updated, don't worry about it, you already removed api url that download json data from your question :)

Comment: @DevShieldMaiden, yes i got you what you have to say...I'll promise you i can change it ASAP. dont worry about it.

Comment: @DevShieldMaiden, I will re run my code in my machine and regarding I will change not only components data but also result, date and id also

Comment: Thank you so much for understanding. Have a great day! :)